# How to send a pyshark packet to specific network interface?

Tags: python, sockets, pyshark

I am able to read a packet from `.pcap` file using `pyshark`. Here is my code:

```
import pyshark
cap = pyshark.FileCapture(pcap_dir) # pcap_dir is the directory of my pcap file

print(cap[0]) # Print a packet
print(cap[0]['IP'].src) # Print some header value
```

Now, I need to send this packet to some interface (e.g. `eth0` ). I tried the follwoing:

```
from socket import socket, AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW
sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)
sock.bind(('eth0', 0))
sock.send(cap[0])
```

But I get the error:

```
    sock.send(cap[0])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Packet'
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. Here is the explanation:

- Use both `use_json=True` and `include_raw=True` to be able to get the raw packet data.
- If you use `print(cap[0])` to print the first packet, you should see a layer with name `FRAME_RAW`. This is the layer that contains the whole packet raw data.

**The code:**

```
import pyshark
from socket import socket, AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW

cap = pyshark.FileCapture(
                input_file=pcap_dir, # pcap_dir the pcap file directory
                use_json=True,
                include_raw=True
              )._packets_from_tshark_sync()

sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)
sock.bind(('YOUR_NETWORK_INTERFACE_NAME', 0))
sock.send(bytearray.fromhex(cap.__next__().frame_raw.value)) # 1st packet in the pcap file
sock.send(bytearray.fromhex(cap.__next__().frame_raw.value)) # 2nd packet in the pcap file
# And so on until the end of the file ...
```