# How to convert pyshark packet to binary value

Tags: python, packet, pyshark

I am able to read `.pcap` file with `pyshark`. Here is my code:

```
packets = pyshark.FileCapture(pcap_dir) # pcap_dir is the directory of my pcap file
```

To print a packet, I use `print(packets[0])`. My question is: how can I convert `packets[0]` to its binary value? For example, this can be useful if I want to send the packet again to the network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. I simply used:

```
packets = pyshark.FileCapture(
            input_file=pcap_dir,
            use_json=True,
            include_raw=True
          )._packets_from_tshark_sync() # pcap_dir is the directory of my pcap file

hex_packet = packets.__next__().frame_raw.value
print(hex_packet)

binary_packet = bytearray.fromhex(hex_packet)
print(binary_packet)
```

Also, it might be useful to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837033/how-to-send-a-pyshark-packet-to-specific-network-interface/54905981)

Comment: How to apply this on Live capture?